# Compact Kähler complex manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Is every compact Kähler complex manifold a flag variety?

Comment: What is a flag manifold? Do you mean a flag variety? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_flag_variety#Generalization_to_semisimple_groups) If so, no. Every complex projective variety is a compact Kahler manifold and most of these aren't flag varieties, e.g. elliptic curves aren't.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes I mean a flag variety i.e. $G/P$ where $G$ is complex semisimple Lie group and $P$ is a parabolic subgroup.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What if this compact complex manifold is embedded as a complex submanifod of the protective space $\mathbb CP^n$?

Comment: That doesn't make it a flag variety.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Comment: (Above I need "smooth complex projective variety.")

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Edited: So to understand it well, Let $G$ be a complex semisimple Lie group (which is-as a fact, a linear algebraic group) acting (algebraically) on a complex projective space, say $\mathbb CPn=G/P$. Let H be any closed subgroup of $G$ .Assume that  its orbit  $H/(P∩H)$ is compact.  Is $H/(P∩H)$ a flag variety?